# Laravel 5: Artisan throw PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, pdo, laravel-5

I've found other question like this but none seems to solve my problem. In my case it occurs on any artisan command, even if I just type "php artisan" the output is `[PDOException] could not find driver`.

I'm running Laravel 5 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with a LEMP stack (PHP 5.6 fpm, Mysql, Nginx). In the `config/database.php` the default driver is set to mysql.

I've checked the output of `php --ini`, it seems to load all configuration files:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

If i open `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini` i see:

```
; configuration for php MySQL module
; priority=20
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

And this the content of `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini` is:

```
; configuration for php PDO module
; priority=10
extension=pdo.so
```

Inside /etc/php5/cli/conf.d i see pdo ini files symlinked like this:

```
10-pdo.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo.ini
20-mysql.ini -> ../../mods-available/mysql.ini
20-pdo_mysql.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
```

The symlink match the base directory `/etc/php5/mods-available` that contains all the ini files:

```
pdo.ini
pdo_mysql.ini
```

That's all. If someone already experienced this, some help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many attempts i finally find out how to fix it: just needed to install `php5-sybase` package. After that Artisan works perfectly!

I guess on homestead it's already installed, unluckily I needed to configure a bare-bone ISO on a VMWare Workstation.