# PDOException during Laravel 5 application creating

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

I just started to learn PHP. I'm following instructions in
https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/

After I set up migration using

```
php artisan make:migration create_projects_and_tasks_tables --create="projects"
```

I edit  /database/migrations/_create_projects_and_tasks_tables.php as it says. But when I tried to excute

```
php artisan migrate
```

I got `[PDOException] could not find driver`.

I'm running Laravel 5 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I changed ~/'myProject'/config/database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

to

```
'default' => 'mysql',
```

Here is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=RCUsYpBg6N0XFaax6BeaKSOCh1s5sNHy

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The output of `php --ini` is

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mssql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_dblib.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

I also installed  `php5-sybase` package as *[Laravel 5: Artisan throw PDOException could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286261/laravel-5-artisan-throw-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver/31294920#31294920)* suggested.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks.

### **Edit 1**

Ran `php artisan migrate` after installed *php5-mysql*
    [PDOException]
    SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

**Edit 2**

```
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

should be the actual username and password for mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql/25336292#25336292

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`